# How to set the numbers to references manually and force them to go in the order determined by the contents of the .bib file?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I am creating the bibliography in LaTeX. I am using biblatex with a biber as backend and
I need to create the bibliography list like this:

[image]

And I created it successfully but the last two resources become reversed:

[image]

The website resource (BIPM.org KCDB) must be located in the end of the list and have the number 8 like on the first screen. I really don't understand why my environment behaves like this. I also tried to use bibtex instead of biber+biblatex, play around with options, swap resources in the bib file... Nothing helped me to resolve this problem yet.

Here is code of my .tex file:

```
%...
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
%...
\begin{document}
%... another content
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is code of my .bib file:

```
@misc{cipm1999mutual:1,
  title={Mutual recognition of...},
  author={CIPM, MRA},
  year={1999},
  publisher={International...}
}

@article{allisy2009international:2,
  title={International framework...},
  author={Allisy, Penelope...},
  journal={Metrologia},
  volume={46},
  number={2},
  pages={S1},
  year={2009},
  publisher={IOP Publishing}
}

@article{picard2016keycomparison:3,
  author = {Picard, Susanne...},
  year = {2016},
  month = {01},
  pages = {06012-06012},
  title = {Key comparison...},
  volume = {53},
  journal = {Metrologia},
  doi = {10.1088/0026-1394/53/1A/06012}
}

@article{kim2017building:4,
  title={Building a graphite...},
  journal={Nuclear Engineering and Technology},
  volume={49},
  number={4},
  pages={810--816},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{morishita2013standard:5,
  title={A standard for...},
  author={Morishita...},
  journal={Radiation protection dosimetry},
  volume={154},
  number={3},
  pages={331--339},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}

@article{shimizu2015comparison:6,
  title={Comparison of the NMIJ...},
  author={Shimizu, M and...},
  journal={Radiation protection dosimetry},
  volume={164},
  number={3},
  pages={181--186},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}

@article{huq2006absorbed:7,
  title={Absorbed dose determination in external beam radiotherapy: an international code of practice for dosimetry based on standards of absorbed dose to water},
  author={Huq, M Saiful},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Citeseer}
 }

@misc{bipm2021kcdb:8,
  author={BIPM, Home},
  title={KCDB. The BIPM Key Comparison Database},
  howpublished={\url{https://www.bipm.org/kcdb/}},
  note={Accessed: Jul. 4, 2021}
}
```

I also found solution at:[here](https://newbedev.com/how-to-customize-bibtex-numbering-in-a-document) using natlib and it partially solves my problem. All resources are in place BUT... ultimately the links in the text don't work -_- The numbers ([1],[2],...) are drawn, but nothing happens when I click.

so, how can I do this with latex/biblatex/natlib or smth? ._.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try using the `@online` type, rather than `@misc`?

Comment: `ieee` is an "unsorted" style (it sets `sorting=none,`), which means that the sort order in the bibliography is determined by the order in which you cite the entries in your document. If you cite BIPM before Huq, BIPM should sort before Huq.

Comment: It will not help with the problem at hand, but Bernard has a good point: You may want to look into using `@online` instead of `@misc` for `bipm2021kcdb:8`. Also try consider changing `howpublished={\url{https://www.bipm.org/kcdb/}}, note={Accessed: Jul. 4, 2021}` to the more semantic `url = {https://www.bipm.org/kcdb/}, urldate = {2021-07-04},`.

Comment: Again, not related to the problem, but the Huq entry (`huq2006absorbed:7`) appears to be a `@report` and has quite a few more authors: https://www.iaea.org/publications/5954/absorbed-dose-determination-in-external-beam-radiotherapy (though it appears to be cited without authors, or so the IAEA recommend).

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! No, and I tried now, it seems no positive result. Also I tried it with bibtex and natbib

Comment: @moewe Thanks! I forgot to mention I tied to one style by the specifics of my task. Literally I need to retype word document to the LaTeX and cause the word doc has a ieee format so the LaTeX doc should be ieee too

Comment: Yeah I will change the type of huq2006absorbed:7 document to the @report. It will be better. Thanks :) I thought and realized maybe my problem is not so critical  and I don't need to achieve 100% compliance of my documents. The main thing is that I understood the principles of generating a bibliography in LaTeX. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Everything works! I just added the missing citation of 7th resource in 215 string. Here is the full project: [link](https://www.overleaf.com/read/pyptbfxcvcgh) But to me it's still magic xD